# How to let Entity Framework execute join queries on 1:1 relationship?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a 1:1 relationship in Entity Framework like this:

```
public class Channel
{
    public int ID { get; set; } 
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public ExternalChannel ExternalChannel { get; set; }
 }
```

and

```
public class ExternalChannel
{
    [Key, ForeignKey("Channel")]
    public int ChannelID { get; set; }
    public string Something{ get; set; }
    public Channel Channel { get; set; }
}
```

The db schema is created properly. When I try to get channels using:

```
var channels = await dbContext.Channels.ToListAsync();
```

I'm not able to access the `ExternalChannel` as its not retrieved. The SQL query is not using join on these tables.

Is there a way to let Entity Framework execute join query so that I can access all data easily? I could do the join myself, but I suspect there is a better way of doing this.

Thanks all for help!

Comment: You are not telling your query to get the `ExternalChannel` data, try `dbContext.Channels.Include(c => c.ExternalChannel)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because by default it does *lazy loading* and so the related entities will not be loaded unless told specifically. You can load it using the `Include` property in designer or in code using the `Include()` on the entity itself like

```
var channels = await dbContext.Channels.Include(x => x.ExternalChannel ).ToListAsync();
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not telling your query to get the `ExternalChannel` data, try using `Include` to tell EF to [eager load](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232.aspx#eager) it:

```
dbContext.Channels.Include(c => c.ExternalChannel)
```